# what is the difference between "prisma delete" and "prisma reset"?

Tags: prisma

I want to delete the **prisma** service and redeploy but I don't want to lose the data. so should I use `prisma delete` or `prisma reset`

Comment: as I found the delete only delete the project and reset delete both data and project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `prisma delete`

But before using this command on production please create database backup. :)

Or better create testing environement.

https://v1.prisma.io/docs/1.34/prisma-cli-and-configuration/cli-command-reference/prisma-delete-ycv9/

> Delete an existing service from the Prisma server its running on.

https://v1.prisma.io/docs/1.34/prisma-cli-and-configuration/cli-command-reference/prisma-reset-ycv3/

> Delete all service data.